# _portaudio.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

My system is Mac OS 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3, Xcode 4.5.1.

I am trying to `import pyaudio` in python. `import pyaudio` gives `Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first`. Considering the error was due to unavailability of `portaudio`.

I installed `portaudio` using `brew install portaudio` successfully. Here is a screenshot of the `site-packages` folder.[image]

But `import pyaudio` still results in `Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first`.
While `import _portaudio` gives `no matching architecture in universal wrapper`
[image]

How do I sucessfully `import pyaudio` in Python?

Comment: I bet someone on the PA mailing list can help if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: I did send a mail but have not recevied any mail from the PA team. If you don't mind can you tell me how to `import speex` in Mac OS 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3 and Xcode 4.5.1. I did `brew install -v speex`, it did some installation on its own but in `Python` it still repots `ImportError: No module named speex`

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea. I was hoping someone on the list would (I don't remember your email) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have both PortAudio and PyAudio removed if you got any of them installed inititally
2. In the terminal, `brew install portaudio`
3. `easy_intall pyaudio`

I got all my errors removed